# How to extract .snappy format file in Ubuntu?

Tags: hadoop

I executed the compression method program in hadoop by using snappycodec method.the output has came in .snappy format.can anyone help me,How to extract .snappy format file in hadoop ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with what are you trying to do but Extracting [Data from Snappy Compressed Files](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Extracting+Data+from+Snappy+Compressed+Files) has described clearly at the URL. you can go there and check.

hope that helps.

[image]